# Connected Component's prop doesn't update in React Native with Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm creating some kind of Realtime Chat App with React Native + Redux. When I get some new message from websocket, internally it will updates list of message as array with redux store. This is what looks like:

```js
import { CHAT_INIT, CHAT_RECV } from '../actions/Chat';

const defaultState = {
    chatList: []
};

export default function(state = defaultState, action = {}) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case CHAT_INIT:
            return Object.assign({}, {
                chatList: []
            });
        case CHAT_RECV:
            let chatList = state.chatList;
            chatList.push(action.data);
            return Object.assign({}, {
                chatList: chatList
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

There are only two actions: CHAT_INIT and CHAT_RECV which can easily understand.

When app receives new message from socket, it will invoke store.dispatch with 'CHAT_RECV' action. This is the component code of list of messages:

```js
class ChatList extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        chatList: React.PropTypes.array
    }
    static defaultProps = {
        chatList: []
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        store.dispatch({
            type: ChatActions.CHAT_INIT,
            data: ''
        });
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log('will receive props');    // 1
    }
    render() {
        console.log('<ChatList />::chatList', this.props.chatList);   // 2

        return (
            <View style={styles.chatList}>
                <Text>ChatList</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(state => {
    let chatList = state.ChatReducer.chatList;
    console.log('Got:', chatList);   // 3

    return {
        chatList: state.ChatReducer.chatList
    };
})(ChatList);
```

I connected ChatList component with ChatReducer.chatList so when new message arrives, props of ChatList component will be update.

The problem is props on ChatList component doesn't updating at all! As you can see, I placed lots of console.log to tracking where is the problem. Numbers next of console.log is just added for easy explanation.

You can see that I'm trying to update chatList props of connected component ChatList, and it should be re-render on receive new props(means new message).

So [3] of console.log prints 'Got: [..., ...]' as well, but [1] and [2] are not prints anything! It means ChatList component didn't receive next props properly.

I double checked the code and tried to fix this, but not much works. Is this problem of Redux or React-Redux module? Previously I used both modules for my Electron ChatApp, and it worked without any problem.

Is there a something that I missed? I really don't know what is the matter . Anyone knows about this issue, please gimme a hand, and will be very appreciate it.

P.S. These are other component codes. I think it doesn't important, but I just paste it for someone who wants to know.

Superior component: App.js

```js
export default class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        init();        // this invokes CHAT_INIT action.
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ChatApp />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

ChatApp.js which actually renders ChatList component:

```js
class ChatApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <NavBar username={this.props.username} connected={this.props.connected} />
                <ChatList connected={this.props.connected} />
                <ChatForm connected={this.props.connected} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(state => {
    return {
        username: state.UserReducer.username,
        connected: state.NetworkReducer.connected
    };
})(ChatApp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mutating your state here:

```
case CHAT_RECV:
        let chatList = state.chatList;
        chatList.push(action.data);
        return Object.assign({}, {
            chatList: chatList
        });
```

Instead, do:

```
case CHAT_RECV:
        let chatList = state.chatList.concat(action.data);
        return Object.assign({}, {
            chatList: chatList
        });
```

Comment: Yep.  @modernator, see http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html for tips on correctly updating data immutably.